# How is the geometry of the magnetic vector potential determined in the original Aharonov-Bohm experiment?

Tags: electromagnetism, gauge-theory, aharonov-bohm

I've tried but I can't find anything about the geometry of the gauge field, which is mentioned in an article in Scientific American 1981, by Bernstein and Phillips.

They say, without explaining it, that the phase shift in the electron beams is modeled by parallel transport around a cone. The cone extends outside the solenoid, and inside it the geometry is a hemisphere. So that gives a cone truncated at a line of latitude on a hemisphere.

This field and its geometry are not detectable in any real sense, unless electrons interact with such a field, so I guess a takeaway is that this gauge field exists in the sense it interacts with quantum phases.

Comment: Are you referring to this article?
"Fiber Bundles and Quantum Theory"By Anthony V. Phillips, Herbert J. Bernstein,  July 1, 1981. 
A branch of mathematics that extends the notion of curvature to topological analogues ofa Mobius strip can help to explain prevailing theories of the interactions of elementary particles.

Comment: Exact reference? Which page? Link to abstract page of article?

Comment: The geometry behind the Aharonov-Bohm effect is discussed in chapter 10 of M. Nakahara, *Geometry, Topology and Physics.*

Comment: @Quillo yes that's the article in question.

Comment: @Kurt G, can you discuss what Nakahara says about the geometry? I'm just curious about how Bernstein and Phillips can work it out. I realise that they're talking about abstract mathematical ideas, the "wet ink" heuristic is actually about tangent spaces, and the fiber bundles aren't physical things.

Comment: I've just located a public domain copy of Nakahara's book and in chapter 10 he does discuss the geometry of the "effect" for a 2d slice through the solenoid. Bernstein and Phillips do this too, near the end of the article where there's a diagram of the bundle over the base space, which is the 2d slice. Interestingly, this models the A-B effect in a superconducting ring.
But Nakahara doesn't discuss the truncated, capped cone the SciAm article mentions along with the diagrams of it.

Comment: [Wu–Yang dictionary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wu%E2%80%93Yang_dictionary) appeared earlier

Comment: Apparently, the [Bernstein and Phillips article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/250802309_Fiber_Bundles_and_Quantum_Theory) is a very good pedagogical introduction into those matters. I just had a quick look at their truncated cone. If you are interested: How geodesics on a cone look like is further discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4726242/what-type-of-curve-follows-a-surface-such-that-the-line-is-straight-when-the-sur/4727780#4727780).

Comment: My recommendation: the geometric treatement of the AB effect was the start of a vast development of applying new geometric notions to physics that culminated in the works of Yang, Mills, t'Hooft, Polyakov et. al. Learning this requires patience and reading a lot of different resources. Last not least it requires asking specific questions on PSE.

Comment: Please look at the vector potential expression [I described](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/746005/magnetic-field-outside-an-infinite-solenoid-carrying-time-varying-current/746013#746013) for an infinite length solenoid carrying alternating current. If you substitute $\omega=0$ into the equation, you get the vector potential form for direct current for an infinite length solenoid. Yes, because it is an infinite length solenoid, it can be very different from the real AB experiment. When I described this equation, I had the AB effect in mind.

Answer (score 1):

The truncated cone from [Bernstein & Phillips](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/250802309_Fiber_Bundles_and_Quantum_Theory) is a very good visualization of the following facts that were found by Aharonov & Bohm:

- The vector  potential $\mathbf{A}$ is non zero everywhere but has non zero curl ("curvature" on the fiber bundle) only inside the solenoid. That's where the magnetic field $\mathbf{B}=\nabla\times\mathbf{A}$ is non zero.
- The truncated cone with a cap as hemisphere is a two-dimensional surface that (similarly to the fiber bundle) has non zero curvature on the hemisphere and zero curvature on the cone part. That's the basic idea of their visualization.
- The rest is better explained in their own words below. A 2D capped cone is not the fiber bundle one really needs to handle this rigorously. This is done
  for example in ch. 10 of M. Nakahara, *Geometry, Topology and Physics.*

[image]